# Selecting the position of drawn text in a canvas using a drop down

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm having issues trying to position the text I created in my canvas through the drop-down menu, so either top left, top right, bottom right, etc I'm not sure what to look up I've tried everything like canvas positioning through dropdown but nothing is working for me.

```
<script>
  function position(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    document.getElementById("myCanvas").position = sc.select();
  }
</script>

<canvas  id="myCanvas"></canvas>

<select class="sc" id="position">
    <option value="0">Select position</option>
    <option value="Top left">Top Left</option>
    <option value="Top right">Top Right</option>
    <option value="Bottom Left">Bottom Left</option>
    <option value="Bottom Right">Bottom Right</option>
</select>

<image id="to_image"></image>

</div>
```

Comment: You have a closing div tag but no opening div tag

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear and redraw on your canvas everytime you want something to happen.

Here's a modified version of the [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_textalign) example, working as you wished.

```js
function drawCanvas(position) {


//Get canvas element
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

//Clear current canvas content
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

// Create a red line in position 150
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.moveTo(150, 20);
ctx.lineTo(150, 170);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.font = "15px Arial";    

// Show the different textAlign values
ctx.textAlign = position;      
ctx.fillText("textAlign=" + position, 150, 60);        


}


//Document loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  //Bind onchange event to the select
    document.querySelector(".select-position").addEventListener("change", function() {
      //get selected value
        var value = document.querySelector(".select-position").value;
        //Execute method to clear and draw content on canvas
        drawCanvas(value);
    })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="200" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>


<select class='select-position'>
<option value="start">start</option>
<option value="end">end</option>
<option value="center">center</option>
<option value="left">left</option>
<option value="right">right</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```